# MySQL timestamp anomaly

Tags: mysql

I've encountered a problem when comparing timestamp data stored in database.

```
'2014-1-1 00:00:00' != '2014-01-01 00:00:00'
```

Could anyone of you tell me why is it so? Why this can't be equal?

Comment: What data type is the first one stored in?

Comment: Doing `SELECT CAST('2014-1-1 00:00:00' AS DATETIME)` does result in the correct date...